# How to uninstall banshee scope in 13.10?

Tags: scopes

13.10 comes with a banshee scope. But it doesn't appear as an uninstall option like other scopes offer. So how does user uninstall this scope/lens?

Answer (score 0):

The Banshee scope is provided by the `unity-lens-music` package (along with the Rhythmbox scope).

There is no option to uninstall it separate from the Rhythmbox scope, but it should automatically be disabled if Banshee is not installed on the system.